# Django - Merge jsonfield's new data with the old data

Tags: django, django-models, jsonfield

So let's assume that I have a model with a jsonfield while using Postgres as a database

```
class Baum(models.Model):
    myjson = models.JSONField(...)
```

Now I'd like to know what would be the best way to edit the model fields saving behaviour/interaction with the database

1. myjson stores nested api responses, so dicts&lists
2. When new data comes into myjson, dont delete/overwrite the old by calling save()
3. -> Instead keep the old data and just add the new data, (if a func which proves that the data is new returns True)
4. I need the data together, in one myjson field where from time to time pairs are coming on top of it. I am thankful for tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```py
myBaum = Baum.objects.get()
myBaum.myjson |= newdata  # dictionary update, Python 3.9+
myBaum.save()
```